# How find a controller class for a request in BroadLeaf Commerce framework

Tags: java, spring, broadleaf-commerce

We are using a BroadLeaf Commerce framework to build an e-commerce site. In that admin can set a roles for user, BLC given beautiful UI to do this functionality. With the help of `+add` button  I can set role for a user and it is adding into database table. But I am trying to debug a code to know the functionality the problem is for that `+add` button I am unable to find which controller is taking the request, can anyone help me how to find the `controller` class?
below is the html code for add button

```
<button class="" type="button" data-queryparams="?sectionCrumbs=user-management--251" data-urlpostfix="/add" data-actionurl="/admin/user-management/251/allRoles/add/"> Add </button>
```

I also tried to post this question in BLC forum, but no use

Comment: You can't find the direct method in the Admin Controller files. Everything is dynamic in Admin. This should help you http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/admin/admin-controllers

Answer (score 1):

- If you inspect adding roles to user you get request url something like

```
~/user-management/-1/allRoles/add
```

- Controller that has /user-managment request mapping is **AdminUserManagementController**
- But AdminUserManagementController methods have only /id mappings so that's not controller that will handle request
- It's super class is **AdminBasicEntityController** and it has right mapping

```spring
/{sectionKey:.+}/{id}/{collectionField:.*}/add
```

- method for adding roles to users is **addCollectionItem**